How to Convert a Complex SQL Query to Hibernate Criteria API
I'm learning about Hibernate's Criteria API and would like to know how to convert this particular SQL query to Criteria API. Here is the SQL query I’m working with:
select s1.score as score,count(s1.id) as rank from
scores s1
inner join
(select distinct score from scores) s2
on s1.score <= s2.score
group by s1.id,s1.score
order by 2;

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Output> cr = cb.createQuery(Output.class);
Root<RankScore> r1 = cr.from(RankScore.class);
Path<Integer> r1Id = r1.get("id");
Path<BigDecimal> r1Score = r1.get("score");
        
CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> cr2 = cb.createQuery(BigDecimal.class);
Root<RankScore> r2 = cr2.from(RankScore.class);
Path<BigDecimal> r2Score = r2.get("score");
cr2.distinct(true);
cr2.select(r2Score);

This is the code i have tried and i don't know how to proceed any further
